# How to enable perl debugger under mod_perl?

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl2

I want to make non-interactive debugging of my code. Code is running under `httpd` with `mod_perl2` enable.

According [official documentation](https://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/debug.html#Non_Interactive_Perl_Debugging_under_mod_perl) I can do like

```
% setenv PERL5OPT -d
% setenv PERLDB_OPTS "NonStop=1 LineInfo=db.out AutoTrace=1 frame=2"
```

As far I understand, I need to use [PerlSetEnv](https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/config/config.html#C_PerlSetEnv_) translating apache `setenv` to language of apache2 config. So config must looks like

```
<IfDefine MODPERL>
    LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
    ...
    PerlSetEnv PERL5OPT -d
    PerlSetEnv PERLDB_OPTS NonStop
</IfDefine>
```

I tried with such config but no output on STDERR when I wrap some code on

```
$DB::frame = 1;
# code
$DB::frame = 0;
```

What could I miss ?

`PERLDB_OPTS` and `PERL5OPT` are exacltly right variables:

```
$ cat 1.pl 
#!/usr/bin/env perl
sub bar { foo() }
sub foo { }
sub hello {
$DB::frame=1; 
bar(); 
$DB::frame=0;
}
hello();
$ PERLDB_OPTS=NonStop PERL5OPT=-d perl 1.pl > /dev/null
   entering main::bar
    entering main::foo
```

Answer (score 2):

This does *not* work for me :

```
PerlSetEnv PERL5OPT -d
PerlSetEnv PERLDB_OPTS NonStop
```

This does, on Apache/2.4.10 :

```
SetEnv PERL5OPT -d
SetEnv PERLDB_OPTS NonStop
```

Outputs to /var/log/apache2/error.log for me, by default :

```
...
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886302 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:         entering DBD::_::common::install_method
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886341 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:          entering DBI::_install_method
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886385 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:         entering DBD::_::common::install_method
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886425 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:          entering DBI::_install_method
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886468 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:         entering DBD::_::common::install_method
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886508 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:          entering DBI::_install_method
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886784 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:       entering CODE(0x18904ff0)
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886823 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:        entering DBI::dr::connect
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886862 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:         entering DBD::Pg::dr::connect
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886899 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:          entering DBI::_new_dbh
[Fri Jun 21 14:43:51.886943 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 24014] [client 127.0.0.1:48278] AH01215:           entering DBI::_new_handle
...
```

Good luck !

Comment: I have `Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)`. Checked, `SetEnv/PerlSetEnv/PerlPassEnv` are all do not work for me :( I can print them as `$ENV{PERL5OPT}` and `$ENV{PERLDB_OPTS}` but perl code is not running with debugger - it gives me `Undefined subroutine &DB::parse_options`. Could you please show me your `PerlOptions` ? I have `PerlOptions +ParseHeaders +GlobalRequest +SetupEnv`